# Replace "0" for "1" and "1" for "0" in the same SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "emp" with the following data:

```
id        name   status
1           x         0
2           y         1
3           z         0
4           p         1
```

How to write a query to change status 0 into 1 and 1 into 0 in a single query?

Comment: Could `status` be `null`?

Answer (score 15):

With a `CASE`:

```
UPDATE emp
SET status = CASE status 
               WHEN 1 THEN 0 
               WHEN 0 THEN 1 
             END
```

Or, with a little math:

```
UPDATE emp
SET status = 1 - status
```

Answer (score 12):

```
UPDATE 
    emp
SET
    status = ABS(status - 1)
```

Comment: In my oppinion, this is a brilliant approach, but only valid for the 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 replacement.

Comment: During the course of Bool functions in university I was curious of replacing them into mathematical functions (and succeeded with all of them! :P ) and that's how I came up with this :)

Answer (score 8):

```
update your_table
set status = case when status = 1 
                  then 0 
                  else 1   
             end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update table set status = not status
```

`true` is an alias for `1` and `false` is an alias for `0` in MySQL

Comment: The best solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code. Its working same as you want.

```
if($_REQUEST['status']=="1")
        {
            $status="0";
        }
        else
        {
            $status="1";
        }
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $q="UPDATE `emp` SET `status`='$status' WHERE `id` ='$id'";
        $qr=mysql_query($q);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `emp` SET `status` = (`status`^1)
```